# Using randomized search algorithms to find weights for neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization

I am currently taking a class in machine learning.  I had mentioned to a coworker that we were learning about randomized optimization, specifically randomized hill climbing (RHC).  He said that it was possible to use RHC instead of backpropagation to find good weights for a neural network.  Unfortunately, we didn't get to finish the conversation, and it's been bugging me all weekend.  Does anyone know what he meant by that?

I've been playing around with Weka, using the weka.classifiers.bayes.net.search.local.K2 classifier...but I'm just not seeing how that would give me weights that could be used by a neural network, such as the multilayer perceptron.

Comment: Hill Climbing doesn't use gradient information, while Backprop does. Thus backprop works / converges much faster.

Comment: I am not an ANN expert, but a quick Google search reveals that the RHC algorithm involves changing a single weight, and see if the performance increases, and if so, keep this new weight. So it's a greedy method. You start with an initial set of weights, then changing one weight at a time, with a random amount (the maximum absolute value of this change might be called "learning rate" in this context) and if the performance of your classifier/regressor/whatever is better, than you will keep this new set of weights, and repeat until "convergence".

Comment: Related to using RHC for ANN training is [Neuroevolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroevolution), which uses evolutionary/genetic algorithms for determining the weights of a neural network. The core idea is the same: they determine if candidate (=weights) get better by their fitness (=NN error/performance). GAs with Neuroevolution might be good complementary information for understanding how such concepts can be used with ANN training.

Comment: You may also be interested in a few other questions about alternate ways to train a neural network, like https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207450/in-neural-nets-why-use-gradient-methods-rather-than-other-metaheuristics/237030#237030 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235862/is-it-possible-to-train-a-neural-network-without-backpropagation

Comment: For future reference, [Genevieve Hayes](https://towardsdatascience.com/fitting-a-neural-network-using-randomized-optimization-in-python-71595de4ad2d) has done a lot of work on this subject, and has developed a python library, [mlrose](https://mlrose.readthedocs.io/en/stable/source/tutorial3.html#neural-networks), to help facilitate.

Answer (score 1):

Recent papers show that there is nearly always some small step you can take to head toward a good solution:
[Saddle point problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2572)
It seems to me that something like random hill climbing (RHC) is fine for that.  In practice I am starting to see that in my code too. For deep neural networks I wouldn't be surprised if RHC and back-propagation were comparable in the amount of computation required.

Answer (score -1):

Random search has great probability of finding you a solution among the top ones, see my answer to [Practical hyperparameter optimization: Random vs. grid search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160479/practical-hyperparameter-optimization-random-vs-grid-search/).

So, with only 60 tries, and a constrained parameter set, you have 95 percent probability of finding a solution among the top 5 percent best solutions (inside those constraints). Great, right? Well...

Actually, it turns out that solution might still be totally garbage, and you might only get good solutions from NNs into the 0.1 or even less percent of solution, requiring even more trials to have a good probability of finding.

Comment: The question seems to ask about training the NN rather then finding hyperparameters.

Comment: @Tim it amounts to the same thing in this case

Comment: Not really. Algorithm that works for few parameters may not be efficient for few million parameters. Pure random search works also quite good for hyperparameter tuning, try it for training the model.

Comment: @Tim I say exactly that on the answer, so we... agree? I don't see your point tbh.

Comment: "might be garbage" does not sound like "it is unlikely to work at all".

Comment: @Tim and then I go to say that you might only find 'good' solutions at the 0.1 or even smaller percentiles