# 2018 Update - Different Algorithms for Hyperparameter Optimization

Tags: r, machine-learning, optimization, hyperparameter

Common question: What are the different options (in common languages like R or Python) available for optimizing hyperparameters? I am primarily interested in implementations in R that can work with XGBoost.

My question has been asked before, but I didn't see any recent revisits to this question. Thorough responses can be seen [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193306/optimization-when-cost-function-slow-to-evaluate/193310#193310).

Based off my search, the most common methods are

1. Grid search, which is inefficient and can often fail to optimize
2. Random search - more efficient than grid search. [see](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/209409).
3. [Bayesian optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_optimization) - Implemented in R with rBayesianOptimization and MlBayesOpt
4. [Particle Swarm Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization). Implemented in psoptim in R.

Past those, what other algorithms are implemented in R? One of the linked questions mentions LIPO for example, but I couldn't find any R package.

As of June 2018, what options we do have?

Comment: I don't think the landscape has changed that much since I last updated my answer (in Feb.).

Answer (score 3):

It's all about black-box optimization. Especially, we are most of the time facing costly black-box functions.

[Here are slides](https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~dambrosio/blackbox_material/Cassioli_1.pdf) of a course from l'Ecole Polytechnique (best French engineering school) about black-box optimization. It mentions:

- [Kriging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging). There is an available [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DiceKriging/index.html) in R.
- [Efficient Global Optimization of Expensive Black-Box Functions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1008306431147), D. Jones et al. 1998
- [An adaptive radial basis algorithm (ARBF) for
  expensive black-box global optimization](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10898-007-9256-8), Holmstrom et al. 2008

Comment: I'm not sure how much of this is "new". The Jones paper appears in the previous thread. Kriging pre-dates Jones by more than 25 years.

Comment: Well indeed it's not "new" if it is not a paper from 2017-2018. But Kriging is still an active topic of research. I mentioned those methods because they were not in the 4 points but were cited in a notable course.