# FIND KNOTS IN REGRESSION

Tags: regression, cross-validation, splines

To find the knots automatically in piecewise polynomial regression, which concept is BEST, cubic splines or k fold cross-validation in python

Comment: You are mixing concepts. CV is for choosing the best Knots. Cubic splines is just a kind of piecewise regression that uses polynomials of degree 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How many number of Knots?

You can use Cross Validation, basically consisting in trying out different numbers of knots and see which
produces the best looking curve.

> Where to place the Knots?

There are multiple approaches depending on the problem, You just could use CV to also chose the positions, or choose one of the following methods:

- Place them uniformly across the domain (common method in practice)
- Put more knots in places where the data varies a lot
- Place them at percentiles of interest (e.g. 25th, 50th, and 75th)

Comment: Spasibo :)  .........    one small doubt, without manually seeing and selecting the best number of knots or using for loop, does CV gives the best number of knots?

Comment: Just try different number of knots with the CV and choose the one which gives a smaller loss, here you have a generic introduction to [CV](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/) ;)

Comment: I could not figure out the application of K-Fold CV in finding the number of knots, can u pls explain in detail

Comment: Run the same model changing the number of knots (refer to [random search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160479/practical-hyperparameter-optimization-random-vs-grid-search)) or the positions of those and take the one which gives you the best results!