# What kind of optimization am I using?

Tags: optimization, monte-carlo

I would like to know under optimization taxonomy, where do the following method fall?

I have a combinatarial optimization problem, that I am trying to solve, 
Maximize an objective value for the finite set of configurations.
(object orientation and position and another parameter). 
Currently I am doing the following,

Randomly sample from each configuration and then apply the objective function and find the parameters that maximze this function.Ofcourse, I dont claim optimalty guarantee here, but an approximation is fine.

Does this fall under Monte Carlo methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like random search: randomly sample a solution, and check for its fitness.

The main recommendation for random search is that it's extremely simple to implement and has a nice probability guarantee associated with it: you only need 60 experiments to have a 95% chance of finding a solution among the best 5% of solutions.

More information:

- [Optimization when Cost Function Slow to Evaluate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193306/optimization-when-cost-function-slow-to-evaluate/193310#193310)
- [Practical hyperparameter optimization: Random vs. grid search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160479/practical-hyperparameter-optimization-random-vs-grid-search/)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the quick reply.  Will take a look at the links.

Comment: "you only need 60 experiments to have a 95% chance of finding a solution among the best 5% of solutions." I think this statement is largely misleading (or maybe I don't understand the context). What exactly "best 5% of solutions" means is hard to define, but, to formally define things, suppose we have a Bayesian problem and we sample parameters randomly 60 parameter vectors from the prior and evaluate the likelihood over those points. If the data is strongly informative compared with the prior, with high probability we will have a *very* suboptimal solution.

Comment: @CliffAB I don’t think you fully understand the context; this is not a Bayesian setting. The links provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in Machine Learning taxonomy this would be a 'grid search' across the parameter space, albeit the grid search is random in nature in your case whereas it normally is more structured in a loop-like fashion.

Comment: Thanks for writing. Grid search across the parameter space with random samples, is random search, right?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_search

Comment: Yes, indeed! I just wanted to add that a pure random search is always a matter of perspective ;).