# How do I select a KNN model?

Tags: optimization, feature-selection, model-selection, model, k-nearest-neighbour

I am considering methods of selecting an optimal K Nearest Neighbors model for classifying a pixel as representing a refugee's blue tarp or not. See https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/billbasener/pixel-values-from-images-over-haiti . The data set has 63,241 observations. I have normalized intensities of red, green, and blue to between 0 and 1, performed 10-fold cross validation, and determined maximum average F1 measure as a metric to optimize. Should I consider 100 values of K linearly spaced between 1 and 63,241 inclusive? Should I consider 100 values of K between 1 and 100 inclusive? If I wish to perform bidirectional selection by transforming the training observations for the KNN model, would I simply begin the previous process again?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your description what exactly is the procedure you are planning to use, but it sounds like a grid search for the hyperparameters and stepwise selection for the features. Both are rather poor choices. Grid selection is inefficient, so unless you can cheaply search through a reasonable range of candidate values, you would miss checking many values. Stepwise selection [should not be used](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection/20856#20856). There are many other possibilities for hyperparameter tuning. [Random search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160479/practical-hyperparameter-optimization-random-vs-grid-search) is a better choice than grid search, but there are even better choices like [bayesian-optimization](/questions/tagged/bayesian-optimization). So answering your question, neither of the choices you are considering sounds great.

If I needed to choose, then the evenly spaced option sounds more reasonable, because selecting among the first 100 values means that you are assuming that those are the only possibilities. With evenly spaced values you can at least try some values outside of this range to verify the assumption. If the optimal value lies outside of the 1-100 range, you in the first case you have no chance of finding it, while in the other case you can at least roughly approach it.